# Constructing nested array based on database data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a template that renders a menu with a predefined structure. I have a database with some menus there and i am already retrieving them. The problem is that i need to somehow make the logic to construct the predefined structure with the menus i get from the database. Here it is an example of what i am trying to explain:

```
export const MainNav = [
 {
   icon: "pe-7s-rocket",
   name: "Dashboards",
   content: [
     {
       name: "Analytics",
       url: "#/dashboards/analytics",
     },
     {
      name: "Commerce",
      content: [
        {
          name: "Blabla",
          url: "#/dashboards/commerce",
        },
        {
          name: "Sales",
          url: "#/dashboards/sales",
        },
      ]
     },
   ],
  {
    name: "Minimal",
    content: [
      {
        name: "Variation 1",
        url: "#/dashboards/minimal-dashboard-1",
      },
      {
        name: "Variation 2",
        url: "#/dashboards/minimal-dashboard-2",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "CRM",
    url: "#/dashboards/crm",
  },
];
```

Basically it is an array of objects with nested arrays/objects.

I really need some guide, i think i need to use recursion but i don't know how. Basically a submenu will have to go inside the content property of their parent object.

Comment: maybe ypu add the data from the data base as well and you try.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `content` key is always the one that potentially has children, check it's length and add a nested loop if it contains more than 1 child.

```js
for (let i = 0; i < MainNav.length; i++) {
     let parent = MainNav[i];
      // create parent nav element here, accessing it's properties i.e. parent.name
      if (parent.content) { //so you don't get reference errors
          if (parent.content.length > 1) {
              for (let v = 0; v < parent.content.length; v++) {
                  let nestedChild = parent.content[v];
                  // append child nav elements here
              }
          }
      }
}
```